# import csv file with conditions imposed

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, csv

```
1.01,Agricultural Business and Management
1.0101,"Agricultural Business and Management, General"
1.99,"Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, and Related Sciences, Other"
1.9999,"Agriculture, Agriculture Operations, and Related Sciences, Other"
3.01,Natural Resources Conservation and Research
```

This is the format of my csv file.some field are inside quotation mark and some are not. If the comma(,)is the part of the field, then the field is inside quotation mark else not.

i used

```
load data local infile '/home/zerocool/UnivHub/database/courses.csv'
into table sub_major columns terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' 
escaped by '"' lines terminated by '/n';
```

Clearly the logic doesn't match here.so no rows are affected.How do i import this kind of csv file. Is there any formula or conditions i can use to import csv file.

```
create table sub_major(code float(6,4) not null unique, 
                   subject varchar(100),
                   primary key(code));
```

i used this sql query to create my table

Comment: `VARCHAR(100)` might lead to truncation. Why not `VARCHAR(255)`? Also try to avoid `FLOAT`, those values can be imprecise. You probably want `DECIMAL(6,4)` for this case.

Comment: ok, i altered my table, now can you please tell me how may i import this csv file.

Answer (score 0):

How about importing the csv as usual to a db table, then try to update corresponding columns by removing " character?

Comment: i can't import, show only 1 row affected.What do you mean by importing as usual? i can't import by using the above command i used.

Comment: I thought problem was occuring when you tried to escape " character ? Did you try it without escape?

Comment: Oh just noticed this from your post: lines terminated by '/n'.
That's not the newline character. It should be \n

Comment: i feel like i am the most idiot person in the whole world. That was exactly the problem

Comment: Happens to all of us :) Glad that it worked. Cheers!